# Multiple parameters on change of select tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am passing id as the second parameter inside `onchange` attribute of select tag like

```
   for (var counterOfLoop in data)
   { 
      var id = data[counterOfLoop]['_id']['$oid'];
      ....
          "<td class='col-sm-2'>"+
                                       '<select id="route_'+ id+'" name="route'+id+'" type="text" class="form-control validate-required" onchange="fetchAllStops(this.value,"'+id+'"")"> </select>'+
                                       "</td>"+

       }
```

When I select anything from select tag, it throws error message at `fetchAllStops()` function.

It throws error message:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input'" fetchAllStops(this.value, –

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below code and try

```
  "<td class='col-sm-2'>" + '<select id="route_' + id + '" name="route' + id + '" type="text" class="form-control validate-required" onchange="fetchAllStops("'+this.value+'","' + id + '"")"> </select>' + "</td>"
```

Comment: Again it is throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input